Webpack build fails silently with no output
I have a react project where I am refactoring the dependency tree and when I run the build I get no output but the project clearly doesn't build. The output directory isn't created. It is almost certainly a dependency issue since I am changing versions of things but I am unable to figure out which one since there is no output.
How can I get webpack to tell me why it isn't building? The verbose logging doesn't produce anything.
The only output is:
$ yarn build:staging
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: "dependencies" has dependency "typescript" with range "4.3.2" that collides with a dependency in "devDependencies" of the same name with version "^4.3.2"
$ webpack --config webpack.staging.js && node set-csp.js
    [webpack-cli] Compiler starting...
    [webpack-cli] Compiler is using config: '<my config path>'

This is the webpack file which I know works since i can use it against the main branch and everything builds.
const path = require("path");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const CspHtmlWebpackPlugin = require('csp-html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
const webpack = require('webpack');

const contentSecurity = {
    connectSrc: [
        <snip> ....
    ],
};

module.exports = {
    infrastructureLogging: {
        level: 'verbose',
     },
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            process: 'process/browser',
          }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
        new Dotenv(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
            filename: 'index.html',
            favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "favicon.ico"),
        }),
        // Copy solution files
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {from: "./src/assets/images", to: './assets/images/'},
                {from: "./src/assets/portal-logos", to: './imgs/'},
                {from: "./public/web.config", to: './web.config'}
            ]
        }),
        new CspHtmlWebpackPlugin({
            'default-src': ["'self'"],
            'connect-src': contentSecurity.connectSrc,
            'frame-src': contentSecurity.frameSrc,
            'script-src': [ "'self'"],
            'worker-src': ["'self'", "blob:"],
            'style-src': ["'self'", "'unsafe-inline'"],
            'img-src': contentSecurity.imgSrc,
            'form-action':  ["'self'"]
        }, {
            enabled: true,
            hashingMethod: 'sha256',
            hashEnabled: {
                'script-src': true,
                'style-src': true
            },
            nonceEnabled: {
                'script-src': true,
                'style-src': true
            }
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(jsoneditor)\/).*/,
                options: {
                    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',                
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        
        fallback: {
            "path": require.resolve("path-browserify"),
            "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
            "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            "buffer": require.resolve("buffer")
        },
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/',
    },
};

